# Не корректно отображается картинка Поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Установил скрипт Поделиться от Яндекса на свой сайт!

Когда нажимаю кнопку Поделиться в Вк то изображения почему то другие не относящиеся к странице

Вот пример: http://bigibig.ru/aid/782/
Движок QPL

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Можно двумя путями:

- Полезно почитать про [микроразметку](https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/211638/) и применять
- Передавать ссылку на изображение в атрибут data-image

В противном случае соцсеть (vk или facebook, например) будут сами приходить на страницу которой делитесь и пытаться найти там какие-либо изображения. Что собственно в вашем случае и происходит.