# Блок ya_share, изображение для вконтакте и статистика в метрике

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Доброго времени. при подключении ya share указан параметр data_image="урл до картинки", но картинка при репосте в вк не подгружается.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki" data-image="http://site.com/img.jpg" data-counter=""></div><br>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

И второй вопрос. Почему может не отображаться в метрике статистика по кнопкам поделиться? Кнопка стоит давно, люди делятся, но в статистике ничего не фиксируется. Может это быть из за отсутсвия параметра data-counter (его не было раньше)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте по несколько вопросов в одном. Про картинку есть ответ [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528021/Не-корректно-отображается-картинка-Поделиться). А в этом вопросе стоит оставить только вторую часть и исправить название.

Answer (score 1):

Вконтакт, facebook и g+ смотрят в OpenGraph разметку, применяйте её для лучшего контроля шаринга:

- http://ogp.me/
- https://yandex.ru/blog/share/1525

Либо уже потом предметно разбираться и смотреть что могло пойти не так.

По поводу Метрики. Наверное стоит написать в поддержку самой Метрики, по крайней мере, по моим ресурсам, я в статистике вижу нормальный поток данных.